# HTML Div in my project sticks to the bottom, how to center it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just cloned this [github-sidebar-project](https://github.com/hosseinnabi-ir/Responsive-Glass-Sidebar-using-CSS-and-JavaScript) And when i am trying to add an div element at the body of the page, it sticks to the bottom of the page and i have to scroll to it.
Also, the sidebar ends when my div begins.

This is the HTML Code i have used in the body:

```
<div class="display">Display</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
body .display {
    margin: auto;
    color: #ff328e;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    background: rgba(10, 10, 10, .65);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px rgb(2, 4, 24);
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .09);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I tried centering it by trying all of the CSS margin options, But they would only let me control the horizontal position and not the vertical.

With this i am trying to add an main element where all the content will be shown for the different options on the sidebar.

Also, i want the div to stretch out to the left side if the sidebar is folded, and make it smaller when its unfolded.

I have these 2 screenshots where i have drawn an red square to showcase where i want this main element to be.

Please note on these screenshots that i have changed some resources but the issue also exists on the original project.

(Sorry, i don't have enough reputation to post these images directly)

Screenshot with folded sidebar:

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1036248150907826282/1048229904124215356/Screenshot_2022-12-02_at_14-30-17_Cashylte.png?width=878&height=440

Screenshot with unfolded sidebar:

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1036248150907826282/1048229335548559390/Screenshot_2022-12-02_at_14-25-12_Cashylte.png?width=878&height=440

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this could be solved by styling the layout of `body` to contain the `sidebar` and the `display` div, for example perhaps try give `body` a grid layout:

```
body {
  display: grid;
  /*  Column names are optional and added just so it is more clear here */
  grid-template-columns: [side-start] min-content [side-end main-start] 1fr [main-end];
}
```

And specify `display` to take the `main` column:

```
.display {
  /*  Specify this to be placed in the main column */
  grid-column: main;
  color: #ff328e;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.65);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px rgb(2, 4, 24);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

There might be easier approaches or other issues that needed to be addressed, but hopefully this would still help as a reference.